# sorting array values of property in neo4j

Tags: arrays, sorting, neo4j, cypher

How to sort an array of values of a property in neo4j using cypher.
for example when the node definition is :

```
 (p:Product {id:[1,9,2,4]})
```

need my query to return ids values sorted naturally :

```
 1 , 2 ,4 ,9
```

tried to look for a suitable function in the neo4j documentation but i couldn't find any array sorting function in the docs ?

Comment: If you have access to the APOC function `apoc.coll.sort` this can be used to sort the array, https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.sort/

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNWIND`:

```
MATCH (p:Product {id:[1,9,2,4]})
UNWIND p.id AS ids
WITH ids ORDER BY ids
RETURN COLLECT(ids)
```